# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation') in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to work with React Navigation using an external button component, to make styling it easier, but it gives me the `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')` error when I try to pass the navigation. If I create the button on my home screen it works fine, but that clutters up my HomeScreen's stylesheet, and means I have to repeat code when I use the button elsewhere.

I have the stack navigation set up in my App.js, and again, it works fine when I'm not trying to pass the navigation as a prop.

Here's **HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    AsyncStorage,
  } from 'react-native';

import Heading from '../heading';
import Input from '../Input';
import Button from "../Button";

export const Home = ({navigation}) => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
                <Heading />
            </ScrollView>
            <Button/>
        </View>
)
```

And here's my **Button.js**

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet, 
    Text, 
    View, 
    TouchableHighlight 
} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


function Button(){
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    return(
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor='rgba(175, 47, 47, .75)'
        activeOpacity={1.0}
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate("New Medication");
          }}>   
            <Text style={styles.submit}>
            +
            </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
    )
}
```

As far as I understand it, this should work just fine, so why is it saying that it's being passed as undefined?

UPDATE: Thanks to some suggestions I now have it to where it doesn't give an error, just does nothing.

Here's my **App.js**, with my navigation

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator 
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="NewMedication" component={newMedScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

class App extends Component{
  
  render(){
    return(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: coz the `this` in functional component is not the same one in class

Comment: @Horst That did help, in that there is no error, thank you. Now the button does nothing, but that is closer.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to pass down the navigation. there is a hook `useNavigation` for that.

Comment: Function components are instanceless, `this` is simply undefined. `this.props` won't work, you can pass the destructured `navigation` prop through to the button.

Comment: @Horst Okay so, I got useNavigation set up, passed the destructured prop and everything, but now my button does nothing when clicked.

Comment: @DrewReese Got it, thank you. I fixed it, though now clicking the button does nothing. I know my routing is correct because I can create the button in my home screen, it just won't take styles if I do.

Comment: please share your navigators.

Comment: Can you drop a console.log or a debugger in the `onClick` handler to verify if it's actually being called? If it is then trace the code up the React Tree to see where it "breaks" and stops being passed up/down.

Comment: @Horst I edited the post to reflect the changes, and added my navigator

Comment: @DrewReese Okay I did a hard reset on my app, and added the debug code. It showed a log. I then added the original onPress back, and got this error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"New Medication"} was not handled by any navigator.

Comment: Looks like it *should* be `navigation.navigate("NewMedication")` sans the space as you've specified that screen as `<Stack.Screen name="NewMedication" component={newMedScreen} />`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a const with screen name and reuse it everywhere to avoid such problem. You nave stack like this `<Stack.Screen name="NewMedication" component={newMedScreen} />` , but try to navigate
`navigation.navigate("New Medication")`.Of course this screen do not exist

```
const NEW_MEDICATION_SCREEN = 'NewMedication'
 <Stack.Screen name={NEW_MEDICATION_SCREEN} component={newMedScreen} />
.....

onPress={() => navigation.navigate(NEW_MEDICATION_SCREEN)}>
```

and for make Button reusable use it like this

```
function Button({onPress}){
  return(
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor='rgba(175, 47, 47, .75)'
        activeOpacity={1.0}
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={onPress}>   
          <Text style={styles.submit}>
            +
          </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
)}

export const Home = ({navigation}) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
            <Heading />
        </ScrollView>
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate(NEW_MEDICATION_SCREEN)}/>
    </View>
```